# Thread1: Program received signal SIGABIRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
Error (Thread1: Program received signal SIGABIRT)

In log file

011-04-29 10:42:16.320 FinalRecap1[1278:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key firstButtonAction.'

NOTE: by mistake i lick the button as UIbutton with name "firstButtonAction" instead of IBAction then i delete all code of "firstButtonAction" from both .h and .m files but Xcode give the error.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check your nib file. You must have a forgotten connection probably on a UIButton or the file owner (viewController), I think it'll look yellow as erroneous.